# Prisma sending non ISO8601 param value

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql

My columns are set to be "timestamp with timezone".  One of my tables also uses timestampz(6).  When looking at the values in the database, they all appear to be the same: "2023-05-25 10:26:32.809521 +00:00".  However, when I pass a date object to Prisma, it formats the param in an odd way: `"params": "[\"2023-03-25 10:26:32.809 UTC\",0]",`

This results in no records being found.  I can confirm this by running my own queries using raw sql:

`SELECT * FROM audit.record_version where audit.record_version.ts = '2023-05-25T10:26:32.809Z'; \\No Records Found`

`SELECT * FROM audit.record_version where audit.record_version.ts = '2023-05-25 10:26:32.809521 +00:00'; //Records found`

It would appear that Prisma is converting my Date object into a String and if I pass in a string date, it still transforms it into the same UTC string format shown above.

Question: How can I get Prisma to send the param in the correct format ("'2023-05-25 10:26:32.809521 +00:00'")?

For further context, here is the where clause being sent to my resolver:

```
"ts": {
  "equals": row.ts)
}
```

row.ts references a Date object.  Even if I set the date to a string (i.e. `"equals": "2023-05-25 10:26:32.809521 +00:00") it still gets converted to the UTC string.  It's also truncating the millisecond field, but I'm not sure if that's an issue yet. I feel like I'm making a stupid mistake, but I can't tell what that is from the documentation I'm reading.  Does anyone have an idea as to why Prisma is converting my Date object into UTC instead of +00:00?

Comment: Which database and prisma version are you using?

Comment: try with toISOString:  `"ts": {equals: row.ts.toISOString()}`

Comment: I'm using Postgres and Prisma 4.13.  Also, I did (at one point) pass in toISOString, but Prisma still converted the param to what I showed above: `2023-03-25 10:26:32.809 UTC`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my issue was a bit different then I thought it was.  The issue was that Prisma was droping the precision of my milliseconds from a precision of 6 to a precision of 3 (the default).  It may be a bug in Prisma as no amount of specifying the higher precision (`@db.timestamptz(6)`) would cause it to alter it's representation.  So, I took the easy way and converted my DB column to have a precision of 3 and everything seems to be working now.  A precision of 3 is probably just fine, but I'm annoyed that I couldn't get Prisma to submit a query param with the higher precision.